# Google Pay API for passes, what is the restraint?

Tags: google-api

I have couple questions about google pay api of passes:

1. How many loyalty classes can we create?
2. What is the daily quota of this rest api call, like how many calls we can make per user per day?
3. Can we send the pass token links in email with a "self generated QRcode"? Or it have to be the "add to google pay button", is this allowed according to google design and use cases?

Thank you for answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How many loyalty classes can we create?

Unlimited

> What is the daily quota of this rest api call, like how many calls we
>   can make per user per day?

"We might limit the rate at which you can call our API. We recommend you keep your requests to no more than 20 requests per second."

Source : https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/get-started/api-guidelines/performance-tips#limit

> Can we send the pass token links in email with a "self generated
>   QRcode"? Or it have to be the "add to google pay button", is this
>   allowed according to google design and use cases?

It's a shame to use a QRCode, especially if the user uses Gmail which integrates Go-To-Action (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/go-to-action).

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer